# My character can't run

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My character can't run. Is it because he is carrying too much weight? Is there a work through on this as I have to make a leap and can't leap far enough to get to where I need.

Comment: If your weight is over your limit, then yes, that's why you can't run.

Comment: Did you buy the Run DLC? :) (Just kidding.)

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Is it weird that I think of [the circa 1988 hip hop group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_DMC) every time I read that?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Ha! I did, too.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Haha, reminds me of [DLC Quest](http://store.steampowered.com/app/230050/?snr=1_7_7_151_150_1) which is full of gems like that

Comment: can you fast travel? if yes then its not because you carry to much....

Answer (score 8):

There is a carry limit in Skyrim, which you can see when you open your item inventory.

Some temporary solutions to **decrease how much you're carrying** are:

- Give some heavy items to a follower
- Sell items if you're near a merchant
- Discard useless items
- If a merchant is somewhat nearby, use whirlwind spirit then wait 1 hour (in-game) and use it again to get closer to the merchant. Repeat until you're at the merchant.

You can do a number of things to **increase the carry limit**:

- When you level up, upgrading Stamina increases this limit by 5
- The [Steed Stone blessing](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Steed_Stone_%28Skyrim%29) increases your carry limit by 100 and any equipped armor no longer adds to your carry weight.
- The *Extra Pockets* perk in the pickpocket skill tree increases the carry limit by 100
- Completing the basic Thieves Guild quests will give you an armor set, one piece of this set increases your carry limit.
- There are many potions (such as Potion of Strength) that temporarily increase your carry limit.

There are many more ways to increase the limit, [see here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Carry_Weight) for a full list.

Getting on a horse will dispel your overencumbrance, and allow you to ride the horse at full speed and even quick travel.

Lastly, if playing on a PC you can open the console with the ~ key and type

```
player.modav carryweight x
```

where x is any number you want to increase your carry limit by (1,000 for example). This is considered "cheating" but it's entirely up to you.

Answer (score 4):

You can also give heavy items to a follower if you have one, but make sure you get them back afterwards!

Also, I don't recall any leaps you 'have' to make, generally if there is an area you need to get to you can walk to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you discover that you could relieve your character from overencumbrance with one item, then drop it and use the carry action to just carry it in your hands. Although you are carrying it it doesn't count as weighing you down. And you can jump and run, just be careful not to drop it down a mountain or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, carrying stuff over your weight limit will make you unable to run. You have to drop some things until you're under the weight limit, or (if playing on a PC) use console commands to temporarily change your weight limit.

Comment: Instead of just dropping stuff and leaving them behind, you can drop something that's particularly heavy and "carry" it by clicking the right analog stick (don't know about the keyboard mapping though). Though I'd recommend going straight for the next merchant, rather than jumping while carrying the heavy item; you might drop it.

Comment: I believe it is 'Z'.

Comment: I'd add that boosting your Stamina on a level up also boosts your weight limit. My first character had a huge problem because I didn't figure that out (He was a mage in Heavy Armour)

Answer (score -2):

If you can't sell an item, you can also leave items in your house, if you have one.  Your carrying capacity will go up any time you increase your Stamina when you level up.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: Another downvote.  Why?  And why especially over two years after the answer was posted?